# Filter List from comparing two List with some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I want to prepare a list of type CampaignDetails after comparing the two list together through Linq. You can see code snippet below:

```
List<CampaignDetails> str = service.GetActiveCampaignBySubCatId(lang, subCatId);  //List1
List<CampaignDetails> sploffer = service.GetSpecialOfferCampaignsForMobile(lang); // List2

List<CampaignDetails> CampList = new List<CampaignDetails>();        
foreach (var data in str)
{
    var CampL = (from offer in sploffer
                where offer.CampaignId != data.CampaignId
                select offer).ToList();
    CampList.Add(CampL);  // getting red mark here
}
```

CampaignDetail class:

```
public class CampaignDetail
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }
    public string CampaignHeading { get; set; }
    public decimal OfferPrice { get; set; }
    public string CampaignDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Whats going wrong here? I am unable to filter the list based on above code snippet. I'm getting a compiler warning at `CampList.Add(CampL);`:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(CampaignDetails)-Method'
>   has some invalid arguments.

Comment: -1 for not providing the error-message and types involved.

Comment: I am just preparing a list from comparing two list based on some condition. I am not able to running my project right now. But getting redmark on the line i mentioned. My question is simple is that from you all. why you unnecessary rate down the points untill you dont know anything.

Comment: _"untill you dont know anything"_ That was the reason for the downvote. _"getting red mark here"_ is not an exhausting description of an error. Actually you have obscured even the fact that there's an exception in a comment. Using `var` is also not helpful because we neither know the signatures(f.e. return type) of `GetActiveCampaignBySubCatId` and `GetSpecialOfferCampaignsForMobile` nor the definition of `CampaignDetails`.

Comment: Will take care of that next time. please upvote and will raise another post regarding this.
Thanks!

Comment: You can even improve questions/answers after you've posted them, simply use the edit-function.

Comment: I have edited and i hope it would be helpfull now.

Comment: No, you've added the wrong types(f.e. `CampaignDetails` instead of `List<CampaignDetails>`). You have not provided the types of the fields/properties in your class. You have not shown the exact compiler warning. I have edited your question to show what i mean.... and undone my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var CampList  = from data in str
                from offer in sploffer
                where offer.CampaignId != data.CampaignId
                select offer;

//in case you want to materialize it,
//or in case you really need a list,
//but this could be unnecessary
CampList = CampList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this method:

```
 CampList.AddRange(CampL)
```

But it would be better if you use LINQ with `SelectMany` method:

```
var CampList = str.SelectMany(data => sploffer
                          .Where(offer => offer.CampaignId != data.CampaignId))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I like your secondary method but i am getting duplicate entries in the list. how can i distinct from the list for above code you mentioned.

Comment: @VedankKulshrestha: what you want to distinct with field? how you check distinct with your approach?

Comment: actually your code gives 1959 entries..i.e (14*140)-1
"14 items in list 1" and "140 items in list 2", "1 = no. of condition match"
above code gives repeatation i.e 14*140 - 1. I want the list (14items - 1) not repeated one

Comment: from above pattern for list is something like this

14+14+14+14+13(condition matched)+14+14+ and so on upto 1959 items in list.. I want (13item list) where condition matched as seen just above mentioned in this comment

Comment: @VedankKulshrestha: Don't understand much, How do you distinct with option `AddRange`? if you wan to distinct using LINQ, you need show the class `Offer` and which properties you need to distinct. Post another quesntion

Answer (score 0):

Insetead of `Add` Use [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method to add the list of items to existing list.

So your code should be:

```
foreach (var data in str)
{
    var CampL = (from offer in sploffer
                where offer.CampaignId != data.CampaignId
                select offer).ToList();
    CampList.AddRange(CampL);  // here change it to AddRange
}
```

Method `Add` in `CampList.Add(CampL)` is used to add a single item to the list. Since you are selecting a list of items (`CampL`) in your query above, you can't use `Add` method to insert in the existing list `CampList`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure CampL is of type CampaignDetails, then you would be able to add it to CampList of type List.